# How to create a SQL var with escape character in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014. I tried to find this string "New Idea [10%]". Unfortunately, `[`, `%` and `]` are special characters and it messed up the query. I need to put the string in a variable for other automation purpose.

I already put some examples that I tried below:

```
DECLARE @sourceLike NVARCHAR(MAX);

--SET @sourceLike = '%New Idea ![10!%!]%' ESCAPE '!';
--SET @sourceLike = '%New Idea \[10\%\]%';
SET @sourceLike = 'New Idea [10%]';

--RoadmapCalculationResults-----------------------------------------------------
SELECT LeverMaturity 
FROM RoadmapCalculationResults 
WHERE LeverMaturity LIKE @sourceLike
```

I think the problem I have is I can't create a string var with escape character.

Any advice?

Comment: What's wrong with `WHERE LeverMaturity LIKE '%New Idea ![10!%!]%' ESCAPE '!'; `?

Comment: As i said, I need to use var. For automation/other purpose. I actually had it working without var, with similar code like yours.

Comment: See my answer and also the demo.

Comment: You could consider having a variable for the escape character. Leave it null if you do not need to use it (so, for example,  `LIKE @sourceLike ESCAPE @escapeChar`). This way you won't get issues with searching for a string like 'Hello World!%'

Comment: If you have a leading wildcard as shown in the commented out examples it is much simpler to use `CHARINDEX` as you don't need to escape anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should works:

```
CREATE TABLE T ( STR VARCHAR(MAX));

DECLARE @sourceLike VARCHAR(50) = '%New Idea ![10!%!]%';

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('C:\James\AAA(1) - C0001506 Mrs Michaela Hysell.pdf'),
('C:\James\AAA(10) - C00 New Idea [10%] rdoza.pdf'),
('C:\James\AAA(11) - C0001517 Mrs Melony Pickle.pdf'),
('C:\James\AAA(12) - C0001518 Mr Homer Guillot.pdf'),
('C:\James\AAA(13) - C0001519 Mrs Lawerence Matis.pdf'),
('C:\James\AAA(14) - C0001520 Mrs Yahaira Hausner.pdf');

SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE STR LIKE @sourceLike ESCAPE '!'
```

Results:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                       STR                       |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| C:\James\AAA(10) - C00 New Idea [10%] rdoza.pdf |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/STLC32367)**

Comment: @SyaifulNizamYahya Glad to help :)